# Why does my csv file which I'm downloading from my node.js backend not contain csv data?

Tags: node.js, csv, vue.js, download

I have a vue.js application with node.js in the backend. I'm trying to build a csv file in the backend and send it to the frontend as a file download. It's not working.

Here's what I'm returning from the backend:

From ListingController.getListingsCSV():

```
async getListingsCSV(user, listingIds) {

/* convert listings to csv string. This is working. */

      return {
        body: headersString + "/n" + csvString,
        type: "text/csv",
        filename: "listing.csv"
      };
}
```

headersString is the comma separate list of headers and csvString is the comma separated list of values.

Then in index.js, which handles all requests, I'm returning this:

```
if (rh.match(event, "GET", "/listings/csv")) {
      const res = await require("./listings/ListingController").getListingsCSV(
        user,
        qParams.listingIds.split(",")
      );
      return new HttpResponse(
        200,
        res.toString("base64"),
        { "content-type": "text/csv" },
        true
      );
}
```

On the front end, I have this:

```
      window.open(
        `/api/listings/csv?listingIds=${this.listingId}`,
        "_blank"
      );
```

When I trigger the download, I get a file whose content is this:

¡¸ÞrÓ›ç-

I have no idea what that is. It's definitely not the CSV I was expecting. Furthermore, it seems to be ignoring the filename I give it: "listing.csv" and naming it "csv" instead (no extension).

Neither the frontend nor the backend show any errors in the logs. The network tab in Chrome and Firefox show only 200 status codes.

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to return this:

```
      return new HttpResponse(
        200,
        res.body,
        {
          "content-type": res.type,
          "content-disposition": `attachment; filename="${res.filename}"`
        },
        false
      );
```

First, I was returning the whole object returned from getListingCSV() as the body of the HttpResponse. I changed that to res.body.

Second, I removed the base 64 encoding since that's not necessary at all.

Third, I added content-disposition to set the filename appropriately.